# Angular 5: ngx-bootstrap popover issue

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

I am trying to add ngx-bootstrap popover to my application. But it only works when I import the popover package in the module I use it. Importing the package in app.module.ts wouldn't work. So, i have to import it in all the modules i need it. Is there a work around for this, so i need not import it in all the modules?

P.S. I am not using system.config.js.

Versions -

@angular/cli - 1.4.7

ngx-bootstrap - 2.0.2

Comment: what you are looking for is a common module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround would be to create a SharedModule which imports and imports the Popover module.

https://angular.io/guide/sharing-ngmodules

Obviously, this is only useful if you have other modules that you need to import in each of your other modules

Comment: Thanks, I was trying the same approach, but I missed to export the popover module from my shared module. It worked after exporting from shared module.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe just use the one I wrote.
https://github.com/MrFrankel/ngx-popper

Its quite advanced.